# Converting Multiple Fixed Width Files to CSV at a time in ADF

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

I have three (.txt) files in a container. I need to convert all these three files at a time to CSV.

[image]

I have converted Fixed Width to CSV only one file at a time.
[image]
But my requirement is to convert multiple files at a time which are available inside a container.
Could anyone please helps me with a solution.**Requirement is, daily we get multiple fixed width text files and we need to convert them to CSV and load them in Tables**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a pipeline, use a metadata activity to get a list of files in the folder.
Pass that list to a foreach loop.
Inside the loop, run the dataflow you show above, and pass to it the parameters of file source and destination.

Comment: As you suggested, I have created a parameter and passed it in the source wildcard `concat('CHWY/',$filenameparam )` but zero column are showing. But I need to derive the columns from the source.